# How to center a flowlayout vertically

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to center a "Flowlayout"-ed JPanel vertically inside another Panel. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
 -----------------
|                 |   
|  one two three  |
|  four five six  |
|  seven eight    |
|  nine           |
|                 |
 -----------------

 ----------------------- 
|                       |   
|  one two three four   |
|  five six seven eight |
|  nine                 |
|                       |
 -----------------------
```

The content should flow, grow and shrink within the bounds of the containing panel and will also be centered vertically.

Unfortunatly all I could master was a top aligned panel which looks like:

```
 ----------------------- 
|  one two three four   |
|  five six seven eight |
|  nine                 |
|                       |    
|                       |
 -----------------------
```

```
public class ListFlowCell extends JPanel
{

    public ListFlowCell(List<String> list)
    {
            
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));  
        list.forEach(s -> add(new JLabel(s)));
    
    }

}
```

Is there a way to achieve the desired behaviour with MigLayout?

Comment: Post a proper [mre] when asking a question.

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to center a "Flowlayout"-ed JPanel vertically inside another Panel

The wrapper panel can use a `GridBagLayout`.

By default any component added to the panel will be centered both vertically and horizontally. So you will also need to set the `weightx` constraint when you add the panel using the `FlowLayout` which will allow the panel to grow horizontally.

Comment: Thanks, I ve been experimenting a bit with GridBagLayout... my panel will be aligned left center but will occupy only one line which will be cut off at the end of the cell with 
```
constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
constraints.weightx = 0;
constraints.weighty = 0;
```
like so...

```
----------------

one two thr

----------------
```

or it will be top left aligned and fill the cell with 

```
constraints.weightx = 1;
constraints.weighty = 1;
```

Any idea how to both fill and center?

Comment: You were asked to post an [mre] demonstrating your problem. Update you question with the MRE using the above suggestion. So you need a JFrame, your wrapper panel is added to the frame and your FlowLayout panel is added to the wrapper panel.